# Search a literal in a zip file

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with oracle bi publisher reports

```
Folder/Usage Trend Report.xdmz
Folder/Usage Summary Report.xdmz
Folder/Charge Trend Report.xdmz
Folder/Consolidation Reports.xdmz
Folder/Charge Summary Report.xdmz
```

Each report is like zip file and contains some files

```
_datamodel.xdm 
~metadata.meta
security.xml
```

I want to make a batch file, searches all the _datamodel.xdm file in order to find a literal (eg INVOICE_NBR or invoice_nbr)
The output will be something like

```
Report Name                    Literal        Usages
Consolidation Reports.xdmz     INVOICE_NBR      1
```

Is there anyone to help me do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please show what you've tried to solve the problem on your own, and where you're getting stuck.  For this time, I found the challenge interesting, so I whipped up a beginning for you.  It's a Batch + PowerShell hybrid script.  Save it with a .bat extension and salt to taste.  Be advised that the regexp object that performs a count of strings uses **case-sensitive** matching; so "INVOICE_NBR" would not increment the count when searching for "invoice_nbr".

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "outerfile=*.xdmz"
set "innerfile=_datamodel.xdm"
set "search=invoice_nbr"

rem // re-launch self with PowerShell interpreter
powershell "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

add-type -as System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# // encapsulate loop into a collection for select | format-table
&{ foreach ($archive in (gci $env:outerfile)) {

    # // create a temporary directory within %temp%
    $tempdir = New-Item -path $env:temp -name ([Guid]::NewGuid()) -type dir

    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($archive, $tempdir)

    # // For each innerfile found within the zip archive...
    gci -path $tempdir -filter $env:innerfile -recurse | %{

        new-object PSObject -property @{
            "Report Name" = $archive.Name
            "Usages" = ([regex]::Matches((gc $_.FullName | out-string), $env:search)).count
            "Literal" = $env:search
        }
    }

    Remove-Item $tempdir -recurse -force
} } | select "Report Name",Literal,Usages | format-table -auto
```

Example output:

```
Report Name               Literal     Usages
-----------               -------     ------
Usage Summary Report.xdmz invoice_nbr      2
Usage Trend Report.xdmz   invoice_nbr      2
```

If you want case-*in*sensitive matching, add the following as a third argument to the `[regex]::Matches()` function:

```
[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But I get an error when I run it 
Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s):

    +  [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($archive, $tempdir)

    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidDataException

Comment: @user494766 Win 7, right?  I'm struggling at the moment to recreate the Win 7 environment on my Win 10 computers, getting `The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.` when I add `-version 2` to the `powershell.exe` arguments.  FWIW, the script works perfectly with `powershell -version 3 "iex...` etc.for me.  I'm guessing in your case, either `$archive` or `$tempdir` or both aren't being recast correctly as strings.  You could try `$archive.FullName` and `$tempdir.FullName` and see whether that makes a difference.